# internal server error using a large fql query

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm running this query:

```
{"my_friends":"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()",
 "check_ins":"SELECT coords, tagged_uids, author_uid, page_id, message, timestamp
              FROM checkin WHERE author_uid=me() OR author_uid
              IN (SELECT uid2 FROM %23my_friends)",
 "tagged_check_in_users":"SELECT uid from user
                          where ((uid in (select tagged_uids from %23check_ins))
                          OR (uid in (select author_uid from %23check_ins)))
                          AND uid <> me()"}
```

and I get "internal server error" when the current user has many friends (more than 200, more or less). When I change the "my_friends" table query and add a limit of 100 friends, the query works fine.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried using the field expansion (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) to get the same nested query effect without using FQL? May mitigate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be caused by some limitation for the `IN` clause. Some SQL databases have this limit as well, for example Oracle SQL supports up to 1000 elements in the `IN` clause. I haven't found any such limitation mentioned in FQL documentation, but it doesn't mean there is none.

Also, I suppose there can be multiple check-ins for one friend, so even if the first `IN` clause works just fine, the second and third might be the problem. So in some cases where people made a lot of check-ins, you will get the error even with the limit.

Try limiting the checkins as well and tell me if it works. It is not the best solution if you need to guarantee that you looked at all the check-ins, though. In this case, I guess you will have to create two queries, asking for the checkins first, then retrieving the info about tags in second query with a limit of its own.